# three-dimensional pixel

Tags: desmos

If we have some function, for example, $$y = ix^2$$, we can express that, (or any) function ($x,y$) with some kind of three-dimensional pixel ($t$ represents the pixel base whose length can be changed, and the values ​​of $i$ can also be changed, in my example). I posted a link where you can see what it looks like. https://www.desmos.com/3d/9df6a98697

If we look at the last two equations, we will notice that they are somewhat similar, that's because they are, and that's because $v$ plays $y$, and $z$ plays $x$ My question is: How to convert three-dimensional pixels into two-dimensional ones?

Another question I have is whether there are similar examples?

Comment: The usual term is *voxel*. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voxel